# Can I eval expression in object context?

Tags: javascript

Good day. I need to eval expression in some object context, but the only solution I found is to create stubs for every object function:

```
 var c = {
    a : function () {
      return 'a';
    },
    b : function () {
      return 'b';
    }
  };

  function evalInObj(c, js) {
    function a() {
      return c.a();
    }

    function b() {
      return c.b();
    }

    return eval(js);
  };

  console.log(evalInObj(c, 'a() + b()'));
```

Show me the right way, please. Can I do it with prototype?

```
  var C = function(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  C.prototype.a = function () {
    return 'a' + this.id;
  }

  C.prototype.b = function () {
    return 'b' + this.id;
  }

  function evalCtx(js) {
    console.log(this);  // C {id: 1}
    return eval(js);
  }

  var c1 = new C(1);
  evalCtx.call(c1, 'a() + b()'); // error: a is not defined
```

Comment: Can I ask *why* you would be trying to do this?

Comment: I try to expand by java programm configuration with scriptable expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function runScript(ctx, js){ with(ctx){ return eval(js); }}
```

closed. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

For late-comers who are still looking for the solution of the issue (or the similar). Instead of using `eval()`, we can create anonymous function dynamically and evaluate the expression in the object context:

```
function evaluate(expression, context = {}) {
  try {
    // console.debug("[DEBUG] Dynamic anonymous function to be defined:\n%s", `function(${[...Object.keys(context)].join()}) {\n'use strict'; return (${expression})\n}`)
    const fun = Function(...Object.keys(context), `'use strict'; return (${expression})`)
    // console.debug("[DEBUG] Dynamically defined anonymous function:\n%o", fun)
    const result = fun(...Object.values(context))
    // console.debug("[DEBUG] Evaluation result: %o", result)
    return result
  } catch(error) {
    if(error.message === `Unexpected token ')'`) throw SyntaxError('Unexpected token, likely at the end of expression.')
    else throw error
  }
}
```

To assert:

```
console.assert(evaluate('a===1 && b===2', {a: 1, b: 2}) === true)
console.assert(evaluate('a===1 && b===3', {a: 1, b: 2}) === false)
console.assert(evaluate('f()', {a: 1, f: ()=>11}) === 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(() =>
{
    // 'use strict';
    function run(expression, context = {})
    {
        return function ()
        {
            return eval(expression);
        }.call(context);
    }

    let context = {a:{b:'Bb'}};
    console.log(run('this', context));      // {a:{b:'Bb'}}
    console.log(run('this.a', context));    // {b:'Bb'}
    console.log(run('this.a.b', context));  // 'Bb'
    console.log(run('a.b', context));       // ReferenceError: a is not defined
})();
```

Comment: you may uncomment `'use strict';` I often use it

Comment: hope you are familiar with ES2016/ES6 or change `(() => {...})()` into `+function() {...}()`

Comment: Salathiel Genèse, I do not see the difference. My code `evalCtx.call(c1, 'this.a() + this.b()')` also works. I need to run expressions without this. I thought angular dont use eval in conrollerscope expressions for security reason. Looks like I also need a parser...

Comment: The `difference` is the use use of `this` keyword which is mandatory. That's why I added that famous `ReferenceError: a is not defined`. Try `evalCtx.call(c1, 'this.a() + this.b()');`

Comment: are you using ES6?

Comment: I use [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) engine, es6 can be transcoded to es5...

Comment: Got it!  `(new Function('with(this) { return ' + js + '}')).call(ctx)` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110348/discussion-between-salathiel-genese-and-lunicon).

Answer (score 0):

The most notable advantage of this technique is that it work without the `with` keyword,

Thus even in `strict` mode

```
+function()
{
    // jsut pollyfills for backward browsers...
    Object.prototype.keys || (Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'keys', {value: function ()
        {
            var result = []; for (var key in this) result.push(key); return result;
        }}));
    Object.prototype.entries || (Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'entries', {value: function ()
        {
            var result = []; for (var key in this) result.push([key, this[key]]); return result;
        }}));


    // here the magic...
    function run(expression, context)
    {
        var variables = {};
        (context instanceof Object) && context.entries().forEach(function(entry)
        {
            entry[0].match(/^[a-z_$][a-z0-9_$]*$/) && (variables[entry[0]] = entry[1]);
        });
        return (new Function('return function(' + variables.keys().join(', ') + ') { return ' + expression + '; }'))()// first get the synthetic function
               .apply(context, variables.entries().map(function(entry) { return entry[1]; }));
    }

    var output = run("a + '#' + b", {a: 'Aa', b: 'Bb', 0: 'Zero'});
    console.log(output); // Aa#Bb
}();
```

Comment: Hey, [lunicon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/602719/lunicon), you are not saying anything about this.

Comment: Salathiel, is it work with functions `run("a() + '#' + b()", {a: () => 'a', b: () =>  'b');` ? only `with` works

Comment: [lunicon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/602719/lunicon), did you mean I it's not working for you without the `with` keyword?

Comment: Salathiel, Thank you very much for your help. I use `function runScript(ctx, js){ with(ctx){ return eval(js); }}` it does all I need